# I'm getting Non-existing setting 'Library Selenium Library'

Tags: selenium, runtime-error, robotframework

In my settings

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
```

is written this way, but somehow the robotframework adds a space in between when I try to run the test and I get this ERROR "Non-existing setting 'Library Selenium Library'". Any ideas why? everything should be the latest version. I have tried also with Selenium2Library.

Comment: That error is showing that you only have a single space between "Library" and "Selenium Library". Are you absolutely certain that your file is _exactly_ like what is posted in the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-selenium2library
```

make sure you have installed it as above and use it as :

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
     Open Browser    https://www.google.com    chrome
```

Comment: I have upgraded it with that already and I have it in the file as you written. :(